# Generate .pem certificate with PHP for PayPal

Tags: ssl, paypal, certificate, pem

i need some help with the follow issue.

A multi user e commerce application uses .pem format certificates to encrypt paypal buttons, until now all certificates was generate with the Linux console with openssl commands.

So far everything works fine, but isn't a practical process if the client has many users, we want users can generate their certificates from their admin panel.

I found the follow script to generate the certificate:

---

```
$dn = array("countryName" => 'GB', "stateOrProvinceName" => 'State', "localityName" => 'SomewhereCity', "organizationName" => 'MySelf', "organizationalUnitName" => 'Whatever', "commonName" => 'mySelf', "emailAddress" => 'user@domain.com');
$privkeypass = '1234';
$numberofdays = 365;

$privkey = openssl_pkey_new();
$csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $privkey);
$sscert = openssl_csr_sign($csr, null, $privkey, $numberofdays);
openssl_x509_export($sscert, $publickey);
openssl_pkey_export($privkey, $privatekey, $privkeypass);
openssl_csr_export($csr, $csrStr);

echo $privatekey; // Will hold the exported PriKey
echo $publickey; // Will hold the exported PubKey
echo $csrStr; // Will hold the exported Certificate
```

---

The output of this script generates me three blocks

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

As a test, I copied the entire block ----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE ----- ----- END CERTIFICATE ----- and stick it in a text file with the .crt extension.

then I'll paypal account and try to upload the certificate, but PayPal tells me that the file is not in .pem format

```
The certificate you are trying to upload is not in the proper format. The certificate must be in .pem format.
```

Actually I have not much experience with ssl functions of PHP and so I turn to you, if anyone can give me some light over this issue, I appreciate it from now.

Comment: did you make sure that you not only added the part enclosed by the `---BEGIN...`...`---END...` markers but also the markers itself unchanged?

Answer (score -1):

I've tested ran your code and sent the result to this verify page
https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html

Seems to generate a correct certificate if you just print the public key and test that.

Seems to be a difference in format between crt and cer for the keys though mainly due to encoding. 
https://support.ssl.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/19/0/der-vs-crt-vs-cer-vs-pem-certificates-and-how-to-convert-them

Test a different encoding or file extension.